# Vue 3 - how to include components and mixins with the root component?

Tags: vue.js

I try to convert the syntax from Vue 2 to Vue 3, but I'm not sure how to include the *mixins* and *components*, if you see this code from Vue 2:

```
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = new Vue({
  mixins: [globalMixin],
  router,
  el: '#app', 
  store,
  components: {
     Thing,
       Hello
  }, 
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Here is the Vue 3 syntax, if I've understood it right:

```
const app = createApp(App)
app 
.use(store)
.use(router) 
 
app.mount('#app')
```

The vue 2 example has a mixin and two components, but how do I add that to the Vue 3 syntax?
You can add a component by doing : `app.component('Thing', Thing)` but that's only one component...should I add them one by one in that way? What about the mixins?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Vue 3, it's possible to do local component registration and mixins in the root component (useful when trying to avoid polluting the global namespace). Use the [`extends` option](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#extends) to extend the component definition of `App.vue`, and then add your own `mixins` and `components` options:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Hello from './components/Hello.vue'
import Thing from './components/Thing.vue'
import globalMixin from './globalMixin'

createApp({
  extends: App,
  mixins: [globalMixin],
  components: {
    Hello,
    Thing,
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

Registering the component one at a time seems like the way to go, especially if there are only a few components.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-local-comp-reg-mixins-in-root-eddnzi?file=src%2Fmain.js)

Comment: Great, I can add the "App" component using "Extends" , this makes it possible to also add mixins, components and lifecycle methods (like "created()") if I want. Thanks!

Comment: this didn't work for me as expected, @mode_x solution worked better

Answer (score 9):

In Vue 3, you can use the application API mixin method.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import globalMixin from './globalMixin'

const app = createApp(App)

app.mixin(globalMixin)

app.mount('#app')
```

For components, you can add them one by one. I prefer it this way because it is cleaner.

Comment: this worked for me better than the accepted solution