# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mixin') Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-mixin, commerce.js

I'm trying to integrate commerce.js in vue 3 ...  I have an error when I try to integrate commerce as a global plugin
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ08Q.png)

In my browser i have a wite screen with this message in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mixin')
    at eval (main.js?fbea:17:1)
    at ./src/main.js (app.js:85:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:337:33)
    at app.js:1518:109
    at __webpack_require__.O (app.js:383:23)
    at app.js:1519:53
    at app.js:1521:12
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it looks like the way you are doing mixins is not the right way in Vue3. Your syntax looks like it would work with Vue2, but not Vue3. See below for an example:

```js
createApp({
  extends: App,
  mixins: [your mixins here..],
}).mount('#app')
```

See this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492165/20053031

I'd recommend just importing this library where it's required.. such as a `Checkout` component if it's only needed in certain places.

Comment: you are right i just tried with your syntax and i deleted the useless import .... but i did not put the mixins in the brackets i did like this : `

` createApp({
    extends: App,
    mixins: [],
    beforeCreate() {
        this.$commerce = commerce;
    },
}).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
`

right ??